# MPAndroidChart values not appearing as I mention?

Tags: java, android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I am working with "implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3' " this library for creating pie chart and the Pie Entry values which I entered manually is not appearing as correctly.
I follow the tutorial and the results in the tutorials were also like that not appearing the correct values.

```
       PieChart pieChart=findViewById(R.id.pieChart);
        pieChart.setUsePercentValues(true);

        pieChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

        pieChart.setExtraOffsets(5,10,5,10);
        pieChart.setDragDecelerationFrictionCoef(0.95f); //how smooth it should spin

        pieChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
        pieChart.setHoleColor(Color.WHITE);
        pieChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(60f);

        List<PieEntry> value=new ArrayList<>();
        value.add(new PieEntry(23.2f,"value1");
        value.add(new PieEntry(92.2f,"value2");
        value.add(new PieEntry(12.3f,"value3");

        PieDataSet pieDataSet= new PieDataSet(value,"Months");
        pieDataSet.setSliceSpace(3f); //between the slice spaces
        pieDataSet.setSelectionShift(5f);

        pieDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.MATERIAL_COLORS); //for variety of colors

        PieData pieData=new PieData(pieDataSet);
        pieData.setValueTextSize(10f);
        pieData.setValueTextColors(Collections.singletonList(Color.WHITE));

        pieChart.animateXY(1400,1400);

        pieChart.setData(pieData);
```

23.2f is appearing as 18.2, 92.2f is appearing as 72.2 and 12.3 is appearing as 9.6
why the values don't appear as I have mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its showing percentage value of pie chart.

please make it false to show real value. like below

```
pieChart.setUsePercentValues(false);
```